# Is it possible to install SpaceVim and its plugins globally (for all users)?

Tags: vim, plugins, installation, spacevim

By default, SpaceVim and its plugins are installed for the currently user only. Is it possible to install SpaceVim and its plugins for all users?

Answer (score 1):

it is hard to implement, because dein do not support root session. BTW I recommend to open issue on github for this feature request.